# read part of text file with values separated by "," insert into an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, file

I have a text file that needs to be read.
En example of the text file is as follow:

```
Login,Name,Surname
Rd-001,Raj,Dolka
RS-932,Ram,Selmen
```

I want to read all the login only and add them on en array so that i can later on add them to a database.

I am able to read the file but i need only the login and its data, name and surname are not needed.

my code is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>reading file</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var reader = new FileReader();
function readText(that){
    if(that.files && that.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {  
            var output=e.target.result;
            //process text to show only lines with "-":     
            output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\-/).join("\n");
            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= output;
        };//end onload()
        reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
    }//end if html5 filelist support
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see the PHP tag, I don't see any PHP code :: Fixed it for you

Comment: What do you mean by "I am able to read the file and not only the login"? I'm having trouble understanding what your desired outcome is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the comment `process text to show only lines with "@":` is not necessary in the given code snippet and might have been copied from some other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that using `split` has been mentioned by other posters, but here is a snippet that actually lets you parse only the logins, given the text structure described in the question:

```
output = output.split("\n").filter((line, i) => i != 0).map(line => line.split(",")[0]).join("\n");
```

The point of the `filter` call is to exclude the first (header) line. The point of the `map` call is to include only the first item in each line.

Comment: How do i add a next line between each login, so that I get the login one below the other?

Comment: Well, the `join` call at the end of the snippet adds a new line character. If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the resulting string in HTML directly. You can probably do this: `join("<br/>\n")` instead of `join("\n")`.

Comment: how can I place the values into an array from here?

Comment: If you omit the call to `join`, then the result of the snippet is an array (and not a string). But now I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. Do you want to have an array or a string as a result?

Comment: I want to place every login value in an array. this is why i tried making it a string so than i can place it in an array of string.

Comment: Without the call to `join` you already have an array of strings. The call to `join` makes one large string that includes all the elements of the array.

Comment: If I want to use the array below within the html code, how will I call it. just calling its name would work?

Comment: Then actually using the large `join`ed string would be enough. So, just to make sure, here is the complete code that lets you display the logins one beneath the other in the HTML code:

`output = output.split("\n").filter((line, i) => i != 0).map(line => line.split(",")[0]).join("<br/>\n");`

`document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= output;`

Comment: what do i do if I want to place these values in a mysql database?how do i post the values from the array?

Comment: I am afraid this is outside the scope of this question. You should ask another question about adding the data to the database and describe your setup and how you connect to the database. The insert into the database will likely take place in your backend code, that is, PHP, judging from the original question. So, you should describe your backend code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `explode()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Or, if you have an CSV file you can use built-in PHP function `str_getcsv`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

I would `file_get_contents` and then explode CSV-file by "\n", 
then `foreach` it and use `str_getcsv` and then save returned array to another one.

If you want to do that using JS, you may use `split()`

Comment: The question appears to no longer be about PHP

Comment: No problem :) You added the extra `js` detail, but @Praveen is already using it in the code snippet originally posted: `output=output.split("\n")`